# Fast binary search/indexing in c

Tags: c, performance, algorithm

I have a dataset composed of n Elements of a fixed size (24 bytes). I want to create an index to be able to search as fast as possible a random element of 24 bytes in this dataset. What algorithm should I use ? Do you know a C library implementing this ?

fast read access/search speed is the priority. Memory usage and insertion speed is not a problem, there will be barely no write access after the initialization.

EDIT: The dataset will be stored in memory (RAM) no disk access.

Comment: Put them in an array. Then accessing the nth element can be done with one single offset computation. (I'm assuming you mean "search by position", since you didn't say anything else.)

Comment: "Do you know a C library implementing this ?" Is it C or C++?

Comment: Is the number of elements 'n' constant?

Comment: Dieter: yes N is constant

Comment: @Kerrek SB: OP says "The dataset will be stored in memory (RAM)". Your suggestion to use an array means that OP will be allocating 2^24 bytes (16MB) of memory.

Comment: dasblinkenlight, C preferred

Comment: Does "random" in this question mean "random" or "arbitrary"?

Comment: @Kerrek and barak: there are n keys 24 bytes long. So n x 24 bytes for a linear search in an array, but 2^192 bits (!) in case of set membership. Possibly in 20 years ?

Comment: @Ben Voigt: My mistake, as well as yours. The size of each elements is 24 **bytes** (not bits, as we've both misread). So even if OP requires one bit for each element (indicating membership of that element), it would still require 2^24 bytes (16MB) of memory.

Comment: @Yves Daoust, setting or resetting a bit would take only a few operations. So set/get operations are done in `O(1)`. The problem at hand is the size of RAM required.

Comment: How much is n ? 10, 1000, 100000, 10000000 ?

Comment: @barakmanos: the biggest problem with this question is that the OP hsan't said *how* she wants to "search" elements.

Comment: @barak: 256^24 or 2^192 is 6.277e+57 bits (Giga-yotta-yotta-bits). There is no such machine on earth.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Odds are good he wants to search by value though.

Comment: @NiklasB.: Maybe, but I don't feel like we should have to guess how to best help the OP.

Comment: @YvesDaoust n is ~ 50 000 000

Comment: And you say that memory usage is not a problem ?!

Comment: @yvesdaoust 50 000 000 * 24 = 1 200 000 000 =~ 1.1 Gigabytes fit in RAM.

Comment: Obviously. But what about cache efficiency ? And what about the option of adding extra data structures around ? Imagine you would like to relate the strings to a simple doubly linked list with pointers on a 64 bits machines: yet another GB of memory !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's a logical ordering between the elements then a [quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) of the data is a fast way to order the data. Once it's ordered you can then use a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) algorithm to look for elements. This is a O(log N) search, and you'll be hard pressed to get anything faster!

[std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) can be used to sort the data, and [std::binary_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search) can be used to search the data.

Comment: Ok so it seems basic binary search is the fastest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use a hash table, available as a `std::unordered_map` in STL. Will beat a binary search (my bet).

Alternatively, a (compressed) trie (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). This is really the fastest if you can afford the memory space.

Comment: Hashing depends on the key distribution and filling ratio, so no absolute statements such as "will beat x", please. ;-)